# How to kerberos authentication with nginx

Tags: nginx

How do I configure Kerberos authentication with NGINX? I want to setup configuration on NGINX similar to the Apache mod_auth_kerb. Is there any recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I was able to do this by using source nginx install with module [pam](https://github.com/stogh/ngx_http_auth_pam_module)

We can even use [ldap](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/blob/master/README.md) authentication.

Ref: https://github.com/stogh/ngx_http_auth_pam_module/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Although this answer covers general auth topics in nginx, such as PAM and LDAP, it has no information about Kerberos at all.  It should not be accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using spnego-http-auth-nginx-module. Here is an article on that topic https://devhub.io/repos/bcandrea-spnego-http-auth-nginx-module

Comment: the link is broken (domain name is up for sale).